# What's the state of the art attack to get the first pre-image on MD4?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, reference-request, md4

What's the state of the art attack to get the first pre-image on MD4?

Is it still $2^{102}$ as described by
Gaëtan Leurent in ["MD4 is Not One-Way"](http://www.di.ens.fr/%7Eleurent/files/MD4_FSE08.pdf) ?

Comment: There are references to improved attacks in this paper http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/583.pdf by Jinmin Zhong and Xuejia Lai from 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest I know about is indeed ["MD4 is Not One-Way." by Gaëtan Leurent (PDF) FSE 2008](http://www.di.ens.fr/%7Eleurent/files/MD4_FSE08.pdf). Some of the more interesting and more recent publications to check on are ["Advanced Meet-in-the-Middle Preimage Attacks: First Results on Full Tiger, and Improved Results on MD4 and SHA-2", Jian Guo/San Ling/Christian Rechberger/Huaxiong Wang, 2010 (PDF)](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225463596_Advanced_Meet-in-the-Middle_Preimage_Attacks_First_Results_on_Full_Tiger_and_Improved_Results_on_MD4_and_SHA-2/file/32bfe5141961404842.pdf) and the paper [Henrick Hellström mentioned in his comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/md4-first-preimage-state-of-the-art#comment13901_7953). I don't think you'll find any more recent and/or note-worthy discoveries.

In 2011 there was RFC 6150 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6150) which stated that MD4 aka RFC 1320 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320) is **"historic"**; meaning: *"obsolete"*. I guess, due to the now *"historic"* status of MD4, there won't be too much interest to expand further on the issue.